# best way to concatenate scope results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I have two scopes. One that checks if db column is null or empty string and another that checks for the opposite (not null, and not empty string)

```
scope :has_something, where('something IS NOT NULL AND something != ""')
scope :has_no_something, where('something IS NULL OR something = ""')
```

I would like to end up with the two results concatenated. ie results that have something followed by results that do not have something

My first attempt was something like this:

```
def self.with_something_data_first
  has_something + has_no_something
end
```

This results in:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `order' for #

because this method is combined with an order

```
Model.with_something_data_first.order(:created_at).reverse_order.limit(20)
```

It would be great if I could could do this in one scope where it returned all records with data then all records with null or empty string. Obviously you can't order by nil but maybe you know of a tricky way to get around this?

Comment: The problem with that is when you concatenate "+", you get an array, not an Active Record anymore, so you can't use order

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :with_something_data_first, -> { order('something IS NULL OR something == ""') }
```

How?

`something IS NULL OR something == ""` evaluates to 1 when something is null or empty string, and since default order is ASC, all these entries will be shown after records with `something IS NULL OR something == ""` resulting to 0

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that is when you concatenate the two scopes, you get an array, not an Active Record anymore, so you can't use order. Don't know if it's the best approach, but you can make a new query from the ids in the order you got. That would be something like:

```
def self.with_something_data_first
  YourModel.find((has_something + has_no_something).map{|o| o.id})
end
```

Like this, you can apply an order method on that, since you're gonna have an Active Record Relation, and it respect the order of the objects you established before. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I ended up coming up with a solution that fit my needs a litter better, but I would of probably gone this way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming up with a solution that better served my needs. Instead of checking for empty strings and null values in the db. I'm going to just switch empty strings into nulls when they entered and use an order like this that puts nulls at the end of the result set.

```
scope :with_post_comments_first, order('-comment DESC')
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple and straight forward. Ideally you should be able to get the result applying both conditions right?

If so, do the following,

```
def self.with_something_data_first
  has_something.has_no_something
end
```

Comment: That would return an empty array